# Unexpected behavior of regexp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, debugging

I've encountered this weird behavior:[image]

I'm on a breakpoint (variables don't change). At the console you can see, that each time I try to evaluate regexp methods on the same unchanging variable "text" I get these opposite responses. Is there an explanation for such thing?

The relevant code is here:

```
this.singleRe = /<\$([\s\S]*?)>/g;    

while( this.singleRe.test( text ) ){
        match = this.singleRe.exec( text );

        result = "";

        if( match ){

            result = match[ 1 ].indexOf( "." ) != -1 ? eval( "obj." +  match[ 1 ] ) :  eval( "value." + match[ 1 ] );

        }

        text = text.replace( this.singleRe , result );

    }
```

Comment: Could you please post your code including the regular expression being used and the text that is being matched? Unclear what is causing this from the provided screenshot...

Comment: could you please share your code and which browser you are using with version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use regex with `exec()` and a *global flag* - `g`, a cursor is changing each time, like here:

```
var re = /\w/g;
var s = 'Hello regex world!'

re.exec(s); // => ['H']
re.exec(s); // => ['e']
re.exec(s); // => ['l']
re.exec(s); // => ['l']
re.exec(s); // => ['o']
```

Note the `g` flag! This means that regex will match multiple occurencies instead of one!

**EDIT**

I suggest instead of using `regex.exec(string)` to use `string.match(regex)` if possible. This will yield an array of occurences and it is easy to inspect the array or to iterate through it.

Comment: What a wonderful and simple explanation. It works! Thank you very much.

Comment: When you do `.exec()` you can do `string.match(regex)` which will return you the whole array of occurences so you will be able to iterate through the array and inspect more easily :)

Comment: You could also do it like this:  `var  res; while (res = re.exec(s)) {  // do something with each result, maybe add to an array  }`.